# go threads sticking around after the load goes down

Tags: multithreading, go, reverse-proxy

I have go based reverse proxy server. When I monitor metrics on the app (using prometheus), Ive noticed that when the load on the app goes up, the threads (`go_threads`) on the app goes from around 20 to about 55. Then after the load goes away, these threads still around, even after many hours.
However I can see the `go_goroutines` and the memory usage go down, but not the threads.

I have a couple of questions

- What is the default size of the thread pool in go?
- How long do idle threads stick around?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I realize this is pedantic as hell, but I can see 3 reasons: 1. Your question is not a programming question, and is probably more suited to the superuser.com site of the Stackexchange network. 2. You really want to know "How can I make a go program free unused threads?", but asked around the issue instead. 3. To a programmer at least, your question might appear to be lacking research effort.

Comment: About the second point, I didn't want to know how to free the un-used threads. I wanted to know exactly what I asked, how long do they stick around. If someone pointed out that idle threads should be gone in say 10 minutes, then that would have been a reason for me to review my code and see what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Voted to move question to superuser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the default size of the thread pool in go?

[GOMAXPROCS](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime)

> How long do idle threads stick around?

[Until the process terminates](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14592)

Notice:

> There is no limit to the number of threads that can be blocked in system calls on behalf of Go code; those do not count against the GOMAXPROCS limit.

This means your best chance to keep thread count low is to have few blocking system calls.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, I couldn't find a default size of the thread pool, however the documentation for [runtime/debug.SetMaxThreads](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#SetMaxThreads) seems to indicate that a new thread is created whenever an existing OS thread is blocked. It could be the case that the Go runtime starts with only a single OS thread and creates more as needed, however that could vary depending on the version of Go.

As for your second question, idle OS threads stick currently stick around forever. There's an open issue https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14592 that deals with closing idle threads, however as of the latest Go release (1.14) there has been little to no work towards doing so.